# Where do I write JAVA code for an activity when programming in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This might be a very basic question but I hope someone of you can help a newbie...

Im doing the Hello World app tutorial and are just about the to add the action bar. So I have declared the action in XML in men/res and as follows:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
     <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
    ...
</menu>
```

Now I need to define the activities by calling methods in Java code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

And my question is, where (in what file and what directory) should I write this? I can't do it in the XML-file, should I use a single Java-file for only this code?

Thankful for any help!

Marie

Comment: If you're using the Android ADT-plugin, which you should, you could simply right click your source folder and do New -> Android Activity. But if you're using this plugin, if you do New -> Android Project. It would already fully configure the Hello World app for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You type the code inside the class files inside src folder. If the activity was created automatically there should be a file called "name of the activity".java. If not open the src folder and any subfolder if there is one and right-click - new - class to create one

Answer (score 1):

you should write you Java code in the src directory. You will need to navigate to src/your.package.name/ActivityName.java. Each activity will need it's own java file in the same place.

For example the default path would be: src/com.example.helloworld/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since you might not want to show the same menus in all your activities, you must tell explicitly that you want to show them in the java code of your activity like you just said.

This is if you have created a basic Android Project with the wizard and it created already an Activity, chances are the file you have to add that in is called MainActivity.java inside src/ folder. This is, of course if you didn't change the name of it when prompted.